# How can i change value data-field in kendo grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am generation a kendo grid with dynamic columns. I am passing columns as a list and bounding using for loop, grid is displaying correctly but will using inline editing its throwing error. i inspect the grid and i found that the fields are appearing as "Columns[0].fieldnams" but it should be like original field name e.g Jun2019.

```
(Html.Kendo().Grid<TeBS.RA.Entities.Entities.ResourceEffortCostPlanDetails>()
        .Name("ResourcePlannings")
        .Columns(columns =>{   columns.Bound(c => c.DesignationId).Title("Designation").Width(150);
            columns.Bound(c => c.EmployeeId).Title("Employee").Width(150);
            if (Model.resourceEffortCostPlan != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.resourceEffortCostPlan.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Columns[i].FieldName).Title(Model.resourceEffortCostPlan.Columns[i].Caption).Width(82)
                    .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @name = Model.resourceEffortCostPlan.Columns[i].Caption });
                }
            }

            columns.Bound(c => c.TotalManMonths).Title("Total Man Month").Width(100);
            columns.Bound(c => c.TotalManDays).Title("Total Man Days").Width(100);
            columns.Bound(c => c.ManDayCost).Title("Man Day Cost").Width(100);
            columns.Bound(c => c.ManDayCost).Title("Total Man Cost").Width(100);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Remarks).Title("Total Man Cost").Width(100);
            columns.Command(commands =>
            {
                commands.Edit(); 
                commands.Destroy(); 
            }).Title("Commands");
        })
        .Sortable()
        .Events(events => events
               .DataBound("onDataBound")
        )
        .Reorderable(reorderable => reorderable.Columns(true))
        .Sortable()
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
        .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(250))
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .Messages(e => e.Empty("No Records To Display"))
        .PageSizes(true)
        ).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "margin-left: 10px" })
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .PageSize(10)
        .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.ID))
        .Create(create => create.Action("ResourcePlanning", "Project"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("ResourcePlanning", "Project"))
        .Update(read => read.Action("ResourcePlanning", "Project"))
        .Destroy(read => read.Action("ResourcePlanning", "Project"))
        )

)
```

data-field for designationid is "designationid"  but for dynamic generated column it is like "Columns[0].FieldName" etc.

please help if anyone know what is the actual issue here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to abstract away your logic into the controller.  The for loop that reads your data into your grid can be placed inside your Controller method and read in the data that way.  As for your error on editing, I do not see any actual calls to make the edit.  You are calling your "ResourcePlanning" method inside the "Project" controller.  Without seeing this code it is hard to say what the error could be.  Here is an example of a project I have.  You should not have to read anything in the actual cshtml file especially since you are using Ajax calls.  It also prevents the need to have a model being sent into your View.  Hope these code examples help you.

My index view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PSAViewModel>().Name("psa-grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.CreatedAt).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
        columns.ForeignKey(c => c.ProductionLineId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["ProductionLines"], "Id", "Name");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 10%" });
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("New PSA Request"))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .DataSource(ds =>
    ds.Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(p => p.Id);
        //GUID of Medium Voltage line for default
        model.Field(p => p.ProductionLineId).DefaultValue("2a23cec5-226f-47be-b97b-cebca5736fa5");
    })
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetPSAList", "PSA"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("CreateNewPSA", "PSA"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("EditPSAInLine", "PSA"))
    )
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable()
)
```

My Controller edit method.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditPSAInLine([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, PSAViewModel psavm)
    {
        if(psavm != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            PSA psa = _psaService.Find(psavm.Id);
            psa.ProductionLineId = psavm.ProductionLineId;
            psa.ProdLine = _productionLineService.Find(psavm.ProductionLineId);

            _psaService.Update(psa);
        }
        return this.Json(new[] { psavm }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to add the column fields as fields in the model  of the datasource in the kendo grid. That way you can be able to specify the field name to get the values from